# Как получить все значения элементов формы через Request.Form?

Tags: asp.net, request, xmlhttprequest

На странице есть n-ое число input'ов. Отправляю данные методом POST. Как мне получить сразу все их id, name и value? Перебирать по одному не имеется возможным, т.к. неизвестно сколько элементов, а name у нескольких элементов совпадает.

Comment: Request.Form относится к enumarable ,  его можно обойти foreach.

Comment: В post-запросе (и get тоже) нету id, для post-запроса используется Name

Comment: @nick_n_a foreach пробовал. Получил name, остальное как достать не знаю. В диспетчере контрольных значений вижу, что там где-то глубоко лежит еще value, но как их извлечь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что б получить все параметры нужно запросить `Request.Form`,
перечислить их по-отдельности можно так:

```
foreach (string Key in Request.Form) {
  string Value = Request[Key];
  }
```

Tак жк можно попробовать получить компонент `FindControl(Key.Replace("_","$"));`

Comment: Пишу на VB. Попробовал написать подобное, не пропускает. К слову, когда бегу просто foreach item in requestform, мне возвращаются строки - name элементов

Comment: Так из name вы можете получить Value через Request[name]. Поправил ответ.

Comment: точно, можно же foreach item по массиву пробежать и запросить Request.Form(item). Что-то не сообразил вчера) Спасибо!)